# Struts 2 + Hibernate: can't catch ConstraintViolationException

Tags: hibernate, struts2

i'm writing web application with Struts 2.2.1 and Hibernate3. I have problem when I try to remove entity, which has one-to-many relation with other entity. I want to implement such scenario: 1)Open session-> 2) Try to remove entity 3) Commit 4)Catch ConstraintViolationException, then rollback and show message to user, that there are related items in another table. But I can't catch ConstraintViolationException! Here is my hibernate config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

```
"-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN" "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
  <session-factory>
    <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.DerbyDialect</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">org.apache.derby.jdbc.EmbeddedDriver</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:derby:c:\soft\db\simple.db;create=true</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.username">app</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.password">app</property>
    <property name="current_session_context_class">thread</property>
    <property name="cache.provider_class">
        org.hibernate.cache.NoCacheProvider
    </property>
    <property name="show_sql">true</property>
    <property name="hbm2ddl.auto">update</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.pool_size">1</property>
    <mapping resource="bytes/ewt/model/Shortcuts.hbm.xml"/>
    <mapping resource="bytes/ewt/model/Categories.hbm.xml"/>
  </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

Mapping for categories class:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN" "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">
<!-- Generated 27 ???? 2010 22:43:18 by Hibernate Tools 3.2.1.GA -->
<hibernate-mapping>
  <class catalog="ewt" name="bytes.ewt.model.Categories" table="categories">
    <id name="id" type="java.lang.Long">
      <column name="ID"/>
      <generator class="identity"/>
    </id>
    <property name="categoryName" type="string">
      <column length="200" name="CategoryName" not-null="true" unique="true"/>
    </property>
    <set inverse="true" name="shortcutses">
      <key>
        <column name="category_id" not-null="true"/>
      </key>
      <one-to-many class="bytes.ewt.model.Shortcuts"/>
    </set>
  </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

Session management I have in web filter:

```
    package bytes.ewt.web.filters;

import java.io.IOException;
import javax.servlet.Filter;
import javax.servlet.FilterChain;
import javax.servlet.FilterConfig;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.ServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.ServletResponse;
import org.apache.commons.logging.Log;
import org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.StaleObjectStateException;
import bytes.ewt.HibernateUtil;



public class HibernateSessionRequestFilter implements Filter {

    private SessionFactory sf;
    private static Log log = LogFactory.getLog(HibernateSessionRequestFilter.class);

    public void doFilter(ServletRequest request,
                         ServletResponse response,
                         FilterChain chain)
            throws IOException, ServletException {

        try {
            if (!sf.getCurrentSession().isOpen())
                sf.openSession();

            sf.getCurrentSession().beginTransaction();

            // Call the next filter (continue request processing)
            chain.doFilter(request, response);

            // Commit and cleanup
            if (sf.getCurrentSession().getTransaction().isActive())
                sf.getCurrentSession().getTransaction().commit();

        } catch (StaleObjectStateException staleEx) {
            log.error("This interceptor does not implement optimistic concurrency control!");
            log.error("Your application will not work until you add compensation actions!");
            // Rollback, close everything, possibly compensate for any permanent changes
            // during the conversation, and finally restart business conversation. Maybe
            // give the user of the application a chance to merge some of his work with
            // fresh data... what you do here depends on your applications design.
            throw staleEx;
        } catch (Throwable ex) {
            // Rollback only
            ex.printStackTrace();
            try {
                if (sf.getCurrentSession().getTransaction().isActive()) {
                    //log.debug("Trying to rollback database transaction after exception");
                    sf.getCurrentSession().getTransaction().rollback();
                }
            } catch (Throwable rbEx) {
                //log.error("Could not rollback transaction after exception!", rbEx);
                rbEx.printStackTrace();
            }

            // Let others handle it... maybe another interceptor for exceptions?
            throw new ServletException(ex);
        }
    }

    public void init(FilterConfig filterConfig) throws ServletException {
        log.debug("Initializing filter...");
        log.debug("Obtaining SessionFactory from static HibernateUtil singleton");
        sf = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory();
    }

    public void destroy() {}

}
```

When I try to remove Category with Struts2 action ()I added system.out for debugging puroses:

```
public String delete() throws Exception{
    if (id == null || id.length() == 0){
        addActionError(getText("categories.update.id.empty"));
        return "operation_done";
    }
    CategoriesManager mgr = ApplicationSupervisor.getInstance().getCategoriesManager();
    try{
        mgr.remove(Long.parseLong(id));
        mgr.commit();
    } catch(ConstraintViolationException ex){
        System.out.println("##Action-catch");
        //addActionError(getText("categories.in.use"));
        return "operation_done";
    } catch(Exception ex){
        System.out.println("##Action-all-catch: "+ex.getMessage() + ex.getClass() );
    }

    return "operation_done";
}
```

And mgr's commit code:

```
public void commit() throws Exception {
        try{
            System.out.println("##Pre-commit");
            getSession().getTransaction().commit();
            System.out.println("##After-commit");
        }
        catch(Exception ex){
            /*getSession().getTransaction().rollback();
            HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession().beginTransaction();
             *
             */
            System.out.println("##Catch-restart");
            restartTransaction();
            System.out.println("##Restarted-return");
            throw ex;
        }
    }

    public void restartTransaction(){
        getSession().getTransaction().rollback();
        HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession().beginTransaction();
    }
```

So, when I call commit, catch(Exception ) in commit method should intercept exception, do rollback and start another transaction, then throw excepion again. Then method delete should catch ConstraintViolationException and add action error about related entities and redirect to index action. But Instead of this, I get exception:

```
SEVERE: DELETE on table 'CATEGORIES' caused a violation of foreign key constraint 'FK8725ACED1BB98B18' for key (1).  The statement has been rolled back.
24-Nov-2010 14:56:19 org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractFlushingEventListener performExecutions
SEVERE: Could not synchronize database state with session
org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not delete: [bytes.ewt.model.Categories#1]
        at org.hibernate.exception.SQLStateConverter.convert(SQLStateConverter.java:71)
        at org.hibernate.exception.JDBCExceptionHelper.convert(JDBCExceptionHelper.java:43)
        at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.delete(AbstractEntityPersister.java:2541)
        at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.delete(AbstractEntityPersister.java:2697)
        at org.hibernate.action.EntityDeleteAction.execute(EntityDeleteAction.java:74)
        at org.hibernate.engine.ActionQueue.execute(ActionQueue.java:250)
        at org.hibernate.engine.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:234)
        at org.hibernate.engine.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:146)
        at org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractFlushingEventListener.performExecutions(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:298)
        at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultFlushEventListener.onFlush(DefaultFlushEventListener.java:27)
        at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.flush(SessionImpl.java:1000)
        at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.managedFlush(SessionImpl.java:338)
        at org.hibernate.transaction.JDBCTransaction.commit(JDBCTransaction.java:106)
        at bytes.ewt.dao.EntitiesDAO.commit(EntitiesDAO.java:34)
        at bytes.ewt.struts.CategoriesAction.delete(CategoriesAction.java:120)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invokeAction(DefaultActionInvocation.java:452)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invokeActionOnly(DefaultActionInvocation.java:291)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:254)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.DefaultWorkflowInterceptor.doIntercept(DefaultWorkflowInterceptor.java:176)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:248)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.validator.ValidationInterceptor.doIntercept(ValidationInterceptor.java:263)
        at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.validation.AnnotationValidationInterceptor.doIntercept(AnnotationValidationInterceptor.java:68)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:248)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ConversionErrorInterceptor.intercept(ConversionErrorInterceptor.java:133)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:248)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ParametersInterceptor.doIntercept(ParametersInterceptor.java:207)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:248)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ParametersInterceptor.doIntercept(ParametersInterceptor.java:207)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:248)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.StaticParametersInterceptor.intercept(StaticParametersInterceptor.java:190)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:248)
        at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.MultiselectInterceptor.intercept(MultiselectInterceptor.java:75)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:248)
        at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.CheckboxInterceptor.intercept(CheckboxInterceptor.java:94)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:248)
        at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.FileUploadInterceptor.intercept(FileUploadInterceptor.java:243)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:248)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ModelDrivenInterceptor.intercept(ModelDrivenInterceptor.java:100)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:248)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ScopedModelDrivenInterceptor.intercept(ScopedModelDrivenInterceptor.java:141)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:248)
        at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.debugging.DebuggingInterceptor.intercept(DebuggingInterceptor.java:267)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:248)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ChainingInterceptor.intercept(ChainingInterceptor.java:142)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:248)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.PrepareInterceptor.doIntercept(PrepareInterceptor.java:166)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:248)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.I18nInterceptor.intercept(I18nInterceptor.java:176)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:248)
        at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.ServletConfigInterceptor.intercept(ServletConfigInterceptor.java:164)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:248)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.AliasInterceptor.intercept(AliasInterceptor.java:190)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:248)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ExceptionMappingInterceptor.intercept(ExceptionMappingInterceptor.java:187)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:248)
        at org.apache.struts2.impl.StrutsActionProxy.execute(StrutsActionProxy.java:52)
        at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.serviceAction(Dispatcher.java:485)
        at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.FilterDispatcher.doFilter(FilterDispatcher.java:395)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
        at com.opensymphony.sitemesh.webapp.SiteMeshFilter.obtainContent(SiteMeshFilter.java:129)
        at com.opensymphony.sitemesh.webapp.SiteMeshFilter.doFilter(SiteMeshFilter.java:77)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
        at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ActionContextCleanUp.doFilter(ActionContextCleanUp.java:102)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
        at ua.org.bytes.ewt.web.filters.HibernateSessionRequestFilter.doFilter(HibernateSessionRequestFilter.java:35)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
        at org.netbeans.modules.web.monitor.server.MonitorFilter.doFilter(MonitorFilter.java:390)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
##Catch-restart
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:128)
##Restarted-return
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:293)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:849)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:583)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:454)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)
Caused by: java.sql.SQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: DELETE on table 'CATEGORIES' caused a violation of foreign key constraint 'FK8725ACED1BB98B18' for key (1).  The statement has been rolled back.
        at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.SQLExceptionFactory40.getSQLException(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.Util.generateCsSQLException(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.TransactionResourceImpl.wrapInSQLException(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.TransactionResourceImpl.handleException(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.EmbedConnection.handleException(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.ConnectionChild.handleException(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.EmbedStatement.executeStatement(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.EmbedPreparedStatement.executeStatement(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.EmbedPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(Unknown Source)
        at org.hibernate.jdbc.NonBatchingBatcher.addToBatch(NonBatchingBatcher.java:23)
        at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.delete(AbstractEntityPersister.java:2520)
        ... 89 more
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: DELETE on table 'CATEGORIES' caused a violation of foreign key constraint 'FK8725ACED1BB98B18' for key (1).  The statement has been rolled back.
        at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.SQLExceptionFactory.getSQLException(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.SQLExceptionFactory40.wrapArgsForTransportAcrossDRDA(Unknown Source)
        ... 100 more
enter code here
```

Please, help me understand such strange behavior (In my opinion) .

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A lot of code going on in there; I'd suggest doing one of following:

- [cascade delete](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/example-parentchild.html), if your design allows you to do that
- before trying to delete, use a select to check if children exist; then alert the user and don't execute a delete

By the way, using string constants like "operation_done" for status checking seems like a bad idea to me. You should rather use a `static final string` for stuff like this.

**Edit**: I think I see where your problem lies.

The following parts:

```
 } catch(ConstraintViolationException ex){
        System.out.println("##Action-catch");
        //addActionError(getText("categories.in.use"));
        return "operation_done";
    } catch(Exception ex){
        System.out.println("##Action-all-catch: "+ex.getMessage() + ex.getClass() );
    }
```

seem problematic. When you catch an exception, be it just an `Exception` or `ConstraintViolationException`, you must rethrow it again for it to be visible "outside" for your delete method. So, that code should be written as:

```
 } catch(ConstraintViolationException ex){
        System.out.println("##Action-catch");
        // addActionError(getText("categories.in.use"));
        // return "operation_done";
        throw ex;
    } catch(Exception ex){
        System.out.println("##Action-all-catch: "+ex.getMessage() + ex.getClass() );
        throw ex;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for reply. Cascade delete not suitable for me. For 2nd point - I consider this as  possible variant, but I'm trying to find reson why I can't handle exception in that way.

Comment: Thanks for update, but it doesn't helped. That exception just caught by web filter and tomcat shows stack trace :(

Comment: @Vitaliy: from what I see, you've taken and modified code in [this article](http://community.jboss.org/wiki/OpenSessioninView). What happens if you use this code without modification?

Comment: No result, fails anyway. I see org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractFlushingEventListener performExecutions in log, which may be related to issue. Does somebody know what is this?

Answer (score 0):

Resolved when I wrote `HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession().beginTransaction();` after commit in EntitesDAO class